# Output text file to TCP port

Tags: windows, windows-vista, tcp, telnet, pipe

How can I output a text file to a TCP port on Windows Vista using built-in software? For example,

```
type TextFile.csv | telnet localhost 1979
```

*This doesn't work: **The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.***

Comment: Shouldn't this be moved to Super User?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The tool to use is probably the windows ports of [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat).

Comment: Dang... beat me to it. ;)

Comment: If you're at work, some AV applications (McCrappy) will identify netcat as a virus.

Comment: SEP identified it as a virus, and it worked great. I replaced "telnet" with "nc" and the pipe worked as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Hak5 talked about just this in a recent episode.

http://www.hak5.org/episodes/episode-511

The discussion starts around 12 minute mark.